# Is it possible to stop the propagation of a taghelpers in one of the taghelpers linked to that tag?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I would like to stop the propagation of any taghelpers linked to a tag.  I have a attribute based taghelper that I use to check whether the user can see or use a tag, and based on that I would like to stop any further processing to happen.

```
output.SuppressOutput();
```

does not work in this regard.

Some more detail.

I have a grid that has rows and actions per row ( actually there are other types of actions, ie on the grid etc) the rendering of the actions happens using a grid renderer.
The actions are added to a context that is provided to the grid via the items property.
I have another taghelper that can be placed on any tag element which determines whether the user has rights to see the element or whether it is disabled.  This taghelper is first in the hierarchy.
Now since the actual action taghelper doesn't render itself, the grid renders it, I can't  suppress the output of the action, as it continues to the next taghelper in the hierarchy and adds it to the context. 
I would like it stop executing the taghelper hierarchy and not add it to the context, without being able to stop the execution I have to now pass whether the action should be displayed or disabled along in the context and update all my various renderers code to handle this.  Stopping the exectution is much simpler and touches a lot less code.

Comment: Please, provide a sample code. *SuppressOutput* does not stop execution, but rather prevents rendering.

Comment: Well is there a way to stop execution up the taghelper hierarchy?

Comment: Not quite sure what is your use case and probably an easier and cleaner solution is available. You can pass a variable between child and parent taghelpers in order to control execution. Other uglier solution I believe it works is to throw an exception inside a taghelper. It should stop taghelper execution but continue page rendering...